# how to add an attachement to an order mail?

Tags: magento-1.9

i am trying to add an **attachment**  to the  order complete email  that is sent right after the order is set to status complete i am using the event observer to catch the event `checkout_submit_all_after` and created a custom function to process the event and get the order  but after that i need help or a lead to attach a file to the email and send it  , any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

1) Rewrite Sales Class

Copy the file found at `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php`
Overwrite the `sendNewOrderEmail()` method found.
Here you need to compose the attachment
Copy the below code and paste it just before `$mailer->send();`
I am attaching a simple pdf file which is inside `var/docs/abc.pdf`

```
$dir = Mage::getBaseDir();
$file_name = $dir.DS.'var'.DS.'docs'.DS.'abc.pdf'; //file path
if(file_exists($file_name))
{
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($file_name);
    $fileName = 'abc.pdf';
    $mailer->addAttachment($fileContents, $fileName);
}
```

2) Rewrite mailer
Copy the file found at `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template\Mailer.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template\Mailer.php`

Add a function and define a protected variable in class `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer`

```
protected $_afile = array(); 

public function addAttachment($fileContents,$fileName)
{
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp['fileContents'] = $fileContents;
    $tmp['fileName'] = $fileName;
    $this->_afile = $tmp;
    return $this;
}
```

Add code in `send()` method. In this method you will need to pass array of attachements
Add below metioned lines just before `$emailTemplate->setDesignConfig…`

```
if(!empty($this->_afile))
{
    $emailTemplate->setEmAttachments($this->_afile); //(by dw)
}
```

3) Rewrite Template
Copy the file found at `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php`

Add below mentioned methods and define a protected variable

```
protected $_filedata = array(); 

public function setEmAttachments($attachments)
{
    $this->setOrderAttachments($attachments);
}

public function getEmAttachments()
{
    return $this->getOrderAttachments();
}

public function setOrderAttachments($attachments)
{   
    $this->_filedata = $attachments;        
    return $this;
}

public function getOrderAttachments()
{       
    return $this->_filedata;
}
```

Add below mentioned code in send() method just before $mail->send() as shown

```
$atInfo = $this->getEmAttachments();
if(!empty($atInfo))
{
    $_file = $mail->createAttachment($atInfo['fileContents']);
    $_file->type = 'application/pdf'; //the type should be as per your file
    $_file->filename = $atInfo['fileName'];
}

try {
    $mail->send();
    $this->_mail = null;
}
```